# Kafka does not require that crashed nodes recover with all their data intact

Tags: database, apache-kafka, bigdata, nosql

can anyone tell me why?I don't understand why Kafka does not require that crashed nodes recover with all their data intact? thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

It's not required because typically Kafka stores 3 copies of the data spread out across multiple brokers in the cluster. Therefore if a broker is lost, it can always re-sync from the other copies of the data stored on the other brokers